# Organize/clean-up clojure library includes with emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

Eclipse has the action 'Organize Imports', which removes all unused imports and cleans up wildcard-imports so that only the actually used members of the imported classes remain.

Does there exists a similar functionality for emacs and clojure-mode?

For example I have the following:

```
(ns some.namespace 
   (:use [some.lib]
         [another.lib]))
```

From `some.lib` I only use `fn1` and `fn2`. `another.lib` I don't use at all. That emacs command would then convert this to:

```
(ns some.namespace 
   (:use [some.lib :only [fn1 fn2]]))
```

Or equivalent:

```
(ns some.namespace 
   (:require [some.lib :refer :all]
             [another.lib]))
```

converts to

```
(ns some.namespace 
   (:require [some.lib :refer [fn1 fn2]]))`
```

Comment: As far as I am concerned: No. It would be great if we wrote this .el file, though.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at slamhound: https://github.com/technomancy/slamhound. You can run it through lein or from emacs via slamhound.el